# how to work with diagonals of a matrix in matlab without using loops?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Lets say I have a matrix and I want to change it's elements. 
How can I tell matlab to go the element in the `(i,j)` place? for
 example:

```
matrix(i;j) ---> if i=j (then do something for example matrix(i;j)^2
                 else ( do something else)
matrix=rand(n)
  if (i=j)
   matrix(i,j)=(matrix(i.j))^
  else matrix(i,j)=matrix(i,j)*3
  end
```

now how can I reach the matrix's diagonals? I am new to matlab and I didn't find an answer yet :\
I am looking for a hint or something but I can't use loops!
hey i got the answer but lets say i also want the opposite diagonal to be in square how can i do this ?? plz any help

```
> if a=1 2 3
>      4 5 6
>      7 8 9 i want a at the end to be a= 1  6  9
>                              12 25 18
>                              49 24 81
```

Comment: if your matrix is called `A` then each element can be accessed through the index of that element, for instance `A(2,3)` gives you the element on the second row and third column.  also `diag(A)` gives all the diagonal elements of `A` as a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that you do not know the basics of MATLAB. Here I will try to explain what you need a little bit, but I encourage you to read the basic documentations of programming MATLAB.

If your matrix is called `A` then each element can be accessed through the indices (number of row and column) of that element, for instance `A(2,3)` gives you the element on the second row and third column.

Also `diag(A)` gives all the diagonal elements of `A` as a vector.

What you have mentioned can be done in different ways, some of which are more efficient than the others but might be more difficult for a beginner. One of the simplest methods is using two for-loops. The first loop moves on the rows of the matrix while the second moves on the column. The goal is to check all the elements one by one.

Here, we use two variables `ii` and `jj` to count for matrix rows and columns. 
`ii` moves on the rows, so it has to count from 1 to the number of rows your matrix has. The same is done for columns using variable `jj`. Moreover, to find the number of rows and columns of the matrix we use function `size`.

Inside the two for-loops we check if the element is a on the main diagonal with `ii==jj` and if its not then you do something else to that elements.

```
for ii=1:size(A,1)
    for jj=1:size(A,2)
        if ii==jj
            A(ii,jj) = A(ii,jj)^2;
        else
            A(ii,jj) = A(ii,jj)*3;
        end
    end
end
```

A way more efficient solution is as follows:

```
diag(diag(A)).^2 + (tril(A,-1)+triu(A,1))*3
```

The firs part calculates a diagonal matrix with the elements on the main diagonal of `A`. The second part gets the upper and lower triangular parts of matrix.

Example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4;
    1 2 3 4;
    4 3 2 1;
    4 3 2 1];


>> diag(diag(A))

ans =

     1     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     2     0
     0     0     0     1


>> (tril(A,-1)+triu(A,1))

ans =

     0     2     3     4
     1     0     3     4
     4     3     0     1
     4     3     2     0
```

Where

```
diag(diag(A)) + (tril(A,-1)+triu(A,1)) equals to A
```

Comment: thank you a lot !! i am actually new to matlab .. but the main problem is that i can't use loops thats why i was looking for another way to solve this !! but stupid me forgot to mention this and i am feeling really gilty for wasting your time althogh i read what you wrote and it did helped me but thats not what i was looking for .. i am really really sorry

Comment: ok i am sorry again i just noticed that i forgot to read the second half of your answer lol ok thats really helped me a lot THANK YOU !!!!!

Comment: how can i accept your question ? is there is something like this ? i am trieng to click on the arrow but it is not working ?!

Comment: Sure! no problem. if you find this answer helpful consider accepting it.

Comment: how :\ because it is just what i wanted ?

Comment: Click on the tick beneath the upvote-downvote arrows on my answer. It becomes green.

Comment: i have another question: lets say i want also to change the values in the opposite diagonal i know how i can take them out .. but i can't figure out how to do it ?? i tried to add fliplr(a) hten do giagonal .. but then i will get wrong result obviously !

Comment: `diag(fliplr(A))` gives the diagonal elements for a matrix that has been flipped left to right. `diag(flipud(A))` gives the same values transposed. Both can be used as opposite diagonal depending what you want to achieve. If there is more to your question ask a new one please.

Comment: i asked one . it would be amazing if you coild check it out because i am almost there..